# proportionality dependent JSpinners in java swing

Tags: java, swing, jspinner

I want to create two spinners in java swing, which will be proportionality dependent each other, so when I change value of one spinner, value of second spinner changes too. 
When I wrote listener for each spinner, cycle was created. I tried use SpinnerModel, but I don't know how to set various value for each spinner. Thanks for responses.

Comment: To prevent infinite loop, detect whether value of spinner is already new value before setting value and triggering event.

Comment: Why not write a change listener that can be turned off and on. So you turn the other spinner's listener off when change is detected on one listener, and then turn it back on again after the 2nd model has been set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not write a change listener that can be turned off and on. So you turn the other spinner's listener off when change is detected on one listener, and then turn it back on again after the 2nd model has been set.

For example,

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

public class TiedSpinnerChangeListeners extends JPanel {
   public static final int SPINNER_RATIO = 5;
   public static final int SPINNER_1_MAX = 100;
   public static final int SPINNER_2_MAX = SPINNER_1_MAX * SPINNER_RATIO;
   private JSpinner spinner1 = new JSpinner(new SpinnerNumberModel(0, 0,
         SPINNER_1_MAX, 1));
   private JSpinner spinner2 = new JSpinner(new SpinnerNumberModel(0, 0,
         SPINNER_2_MAX, SPINNER_RATIO));

   public TiedSpinnerChangeListeners() {
      add(spinner1);
      add(spinner2);

      TiedSpinnerListener spinnerListener1 = new TiedSpinnerListener(spinner2, false);
      TiedSpinnerListener spinnerListener2 = new TiedSpinnerListener(spinner1, true);
      spinnerListener1.setSecondSpinnerListener(spinnerListener2);
      spinnerListener2.setSecondSpinnerListener(spinnerListener1);
      spinner1.addChangeListener(spinnerListener1);
      spinner2.addChangeListener(spinnerListener2);


   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("GUI");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(new TiedSpinnerChangeListeners());
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}

class TiedSpinnerListener implements ChangeListener {
   private TiedSpinnerListener secondSpinnerListener;
   private JSpinner secondSpinner;
   private boolean listenerOn = true;
   private boolean largerValue;

   public TiedSpinnerListener(JSpinner secondSpinner,
         boolean largerValue) {
      this.secondSpinner = secondSpinner;
      this.largerValue = largerValue;
   }

   @Override
   public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
      if (!listenerOn) {
         return;
      }
      secondSpinnerListener.setListenerOn(false);
      int value = ((Integer) ((JSpinner) e.getSource()).getValue()).intValue();

      int newValue = largerValue ? value
            / TiedSpinnerChangeListeners.SPINNER_RATIO : value
            * TiedSpinnerChangeListeners.SPINNER_RATIO;
      secondSpinner.setValue(newValue);
      secondSpinnerListener.setListenerOn(true);
   }

   public void setSecondSpinnerListener(TiedSpinnerListener secondSpinnerListener) {
      this.secondSpinnerListener = secondSpinnerListener;
   }

   public boolean isListenerOn() {
      return listenerOn;
   }

   public void setListenerOn(boolean listenerOn) {
      this.listenerOn = listenerOn;
   }

}
```